iOS Vision Face Detection coordinates not working with DockKit while correct on preview layer
I'm trying to implement face detection using Vision framework with the following setup:

Back camera in portrait mode
VNImageRequestHandler with .leftMirrored orientation
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer for preview
DockKit for face tracking

Current implementation:
class TestViewController: UIViewController {
    private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    private let videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    
    private lazy var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
    
    private var faceLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []
    private var dockAccessory: DockAccessory?
    private var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Task {
            try await DockAccessoryManager.shared.setSystemTrackingEnabled(false)
            
            for await accessory in try DockAccessoryManager.shared.accessoryStateChanges {
                print(accessory.state)
               
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //self.connectedToDock = accessory.state == DockAccessory.State.docked
                    self.dockAccessory = accessory.accessory
                }
            }
        }
        
        setupCamera()
        captureSession.startRunning()
        
        func setupCamera() {
            self.captureSession.sessionPreset = .hd1280x720
            let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(
                deviceTypes: [
                    .builtInDualCamera,
                    .builtInTripleCamera
                ],
                mediaType: .video,
                position: .back
            )
            if let device = deviceDiscoverySession.devices.first {
                if let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
                    if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
                        captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
                        
                        setupPreview()
                    }
                }
                
                self.captureDevice = device
            }
            
            func setupPreview() {
                self.previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
                self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.frame
                
                self.videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [
                    (kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
                ] as [String : Any]

                self.videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(
                    self,
                    queue: DispatchQueue(label: "camera queue")
                )
                self.captureSession.addOutput(self.videoDataOutput)
                
                let videoConnection = self.videoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)
                videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var frameCounter = 0
    private var lastTimestamp = Date()
}

extension TestViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
          return
        }

        let faceDetectionRequest = VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest(completionHandler: { (request: VNRequest, error: Error?) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.faceLayers.forEach({ drawing in drawing.removeFromSuperlayer() })

                if let observations = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation] {
                    self.handleFaceDetectionObservations(
                        observations: observations,
                        imageBuffer,
                        sampleBuffer
                    )
                }
            }
        })
        
        let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: imageBuffer, orientation: .leftMirrored, options: [:])
        
        do {
            try imageRequestHandler.perform([faceDetectionRequest])
        } catch {
          print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    
    private func handleFaceDetectionObservations(
        observations: [VNFaceObservation],
        _ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer,
        _ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer
    ) {
        for observation in observations {
            var faceRectConverted = self.previewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: observation.boundingBox)
            let faceRectanglePath = CGPath(rect: faceRectConverted, transform: nil)
            
            let faceLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            faceLayer.path = faceRectanglePath
            faceLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            faceLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
            
            self.faceLayers.append(faceLayer)
            self.view.layer.addSublayer(faceLayer)
            
            if
                let captureDevice = captureDevice,
                let dockAccessory = dockAccessory
            {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await trackWithDockKit(
                            observation.boundingBox,
                            dockAccessory,
                            pixelBuffer,
                            sampleBuffer
                        )
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func trackWithDockKit(_ boundingBox: CGRect, _ dockAccessory: DockAccessory, _ pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer, _ cmSampelBuffer: CMSampleBuffer) async throws {
        guard
            let device = captureDevice
        else {
            fatalError("Kamera nicht verfügbar")
        }
        
        let size = CGSize(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))
        
        let cameraInfo = DockAccessory.CameraInformation(
            captureDevice: device.deviceType,
            cameraPosition: device.position,
            orientation: .corrected,
            cameraIntrinsics: nil,
            referenceDimensions: size
        )
        
        let observation = DockAccessory.Observation(
            identifier: 0,
            type: .object,
            rect: boundingBox
        )
        let observations = [observation]
        
        try await dockAccessory.track(observations, cameraInformation: cameraInfo)
    }
}

What works:

Face detection works correctly
Drawing bounding boxes on the preview layer works perfectly using layerRectConverted

What doesn't work:

DockKit face tracking doesn't align with the actual faces

Example coordinates:
Vision gives me normalized coordinates like: (0.220, 0.051, 0.347, 0.618)
Question:
What am I missing in terms of coordinate transformation? The bounding boxes render correctly on screen using layerRectConverted, but DockKit seems to expect the coordinates in a different format. How can I properly transform the Vision coordinates for DockKit?
